# Combine two different lists C#

Tags: c#, linq

i have two classes

```
public class AuditResults
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
    }

public class AuditResults2
    {
        public int Channel_ID { get; set; }
        public bool Available_Item{ get; set; }
    }
```

AuditResults will have multiple rows returned from query, while AuditResults2 will have only one.

I want to combine there all results to something like

```
[
      {
      "ID": "1",
      "Question": "Question 1 here",
   },
      {
      "ID": "3",
      "Question": "Question 3 here",
   },
     "Channel_ID" : true,
     "Available_Item" : false
]
```

if i make a third class which contain both other classes objects, can i add 2 classes results in 3rd one.

```
public class AuditResultsFinal
    {
        public AuditResults AuditResults {get; set;}
        public AuditResults2 AuditResults2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Results of AuditResults

```
List<AuditResults> myResults = Database.SqlQuery<AuditResults>(query,model.UserName).ToList();
```

Results of AuditResults2

```
List<AuditResults2> myResults2 = Database.SqlQuery<AuditResults2>(query,model.UserName).ToList();
```

What to do here to combine above 2 results in myFinalResults:

```
List<AuditResultsFinal> myFinalResults = new List<AuditResultsFinal>();
```

Comment: How do you know which `AuditResults` belongs to which `AuditResults2`?

Comment: AuditResults and AuditResults2 both have different results , i just want them all to be returned in one myFinalResults. Like the above Json sample.

Comment: Looking at your code, don't you just need to assign `AuditResults` and `AuditResults2` properties when constructing `myFinalResult` object?

Comment: Available_Item is bool but in jSON it's showing 20. How?

Comment: Wouldn't it then make more sense for `AuditResultsFinal` to contain 2 `List<>` instead of 2 instances and return a single `AuditResultsFinal` instance from the call?

Comment: oops sorry, yes it should be true false. that is s mistake, how do i add myresults and myresults2 in myFInalResults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need List of AuditResults in your final class. So You need to make it List type. Change your **AuditResultsFinal** as below

```
public class AuditResultsFinal
    {
        public List<AuditResults> AuditResults { get; set; }
        public List<AuditResults2> AuditResults2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Then You can assign List of **AuditResults** and **AuditResults2** in your **AuditResultsFinal**.

```
var AuditResults1 = new List<AuditResults>{
                new AuditResults{ID="1",Question="Q1"},
                new AuditResults{ID="2",Question="Q2"}
            };

            var AuditResults2 = new List<AuditResults2>{
                new AuditResults2{Channel_ID=3,Available_Item=true},
                new AuditResults2{Channel_ID=4,Available_Item=false}
            };

            AuditResultsFinal final = new AuditResultsFinal()
            {
                AuditResults = AuditResults1,
                AuditResults2 = AuditResults2
            };
```

Comment: Thank You, i am getting response like below and it will work for me:
`{
   "AuditResults":    [
            {
         "ID": "1",
         "Question": "Question1"
      },
            {
         "ID": "3",
         "Question": "Question3"
      }
   ],
   "AuditResults2": [   {
      "Channel_ID": 1,
      "Available_Item": true
   }]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this under the condition that you do not care about, which objects come together in `AuditResultsFinal` and that both Lists have the same length.

```
var result = new List<AuditResultsFinal>();

for(var i = 0; i < myResults.Count; i++)
{
   res.Add(new AuditResultsFinal() { AuditResults = myResults[i], AuditResults2 = myResults2[i] });
}
```